# How to catch exceptions.NoFilesFound error from awswrangler in Python 3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, exception, parquet, aws-data-wrangler

Here is my code to read the parquet files stored in an S3 bucket path. When it finds the parquet files in the path, it works, but gives `exceptions.NoFilesFound` when it cannot find any file.

```
import boto3
import awswrangler as wr
    
boto3.setup_default_session(profile_name="myAwsProfile", region_name="us-east-1")
    
path_prefix  = 's3://example_bucket/data/parquet_files'
path_suffix = '/y=2021/m=4/d=13/h=17/'
table_path = path_prefix + path_suffix

df = wr.s3.read_parquet(path=table_path)
print(len(df))
```

Output:

```
22646
```

If there is no file in the S3 path, for example, if I change the `path_suffix` from `'/y=2021/m=4/d=13/h=17/'` to `'/y=2021/m=4/d=13/h=170/'`, I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NoFilesFound                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-17df460412d8> in <module>
     11 
     12 file_prefix = table_path + date_prefix
---> 13 df = wr.s3.read_parquet(path=file_prefix)

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/awswrangler/s3/_read_parquet.py in read_parquet(path, path_suffix, path_ignore_suffix, ignore_empty, ignore_index, partition_filter, columns, validate_schema, chunked, dataset, categories, safe, map_types, use_threads, last_modified_begin, last_modified_end, boto3_session, s3_additional_kwargs)
    602         paths = _apply_partition_filter(path_root=path_root, paths=paths, filter_func=partition_filter)
    603     if len(paths) < 1:
--> 604         raise exceptions.NoFilesFound(f"No files Found on: {path}.")
    605     _logger.debug("paths:\n%s", paths)
    606     args: Dict[str, Any] = {

NoFilesFound: No files Found on: s3://example_bucket/data/parquet_files/y=2021/m=4/d=13/h=170/.
```

Looks like it is coming from `awswrangler` Python library, so botocore.exceptions can't catch it. I can simply use python's `try:` and `except:` to bypass, but I need to catch it to properly handle it. How can I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to just catch the exception,

```
from awswrangler import exceptions
try:
  ...
except exceptions.NoFilesFound:
  ...
```